# Error compiling simple Java File: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

What can be the problem when I'm compiling `Tareena.java` file in my C:/FindTheWallet/Proj/ folder? I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

Here is my code below:

```
class Tareena 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Still working on it ? ");
    }
}
```

Comment: ClassFoundException does not happen when compiling Java source files.  Do you mean when you are trying to run the program?

Comment: I would bet you're not compiling. You're trying to run it. Call it using javac instead of java.

Comment: Please show us what's in your console (commands you're typing, and their output)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is `Tareena.class` is not in your classpath when you are running your program. Follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

Compile your class first using `javac Tareena.java` and then execute it using `java Tareena`